# how to detect if NSInteger is between 10 and 20

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsinteger

Hi I have tried multiple things combining knowledge of mine and the internet but I cannot find a way to check if an NSInteger is between 10 and 20.

Would it be something like this? (it didn't work)

```
if (FXVolumeSlider.value == 10-20) {}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sad this is closed. I was hoping there was a one-method solution like `[FXVolumeSlider.value isBetween:10 and:20]`. Cocoa has these cool shortcuts sprinkled all around, after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inclusive...

```
if (FXVolumeSlider.value >= 10 && FXVolumeSlider.value <= 20) {}
```

Exclusive...

```
if (FXVolumeSlider.value > 10 && FXVolumeSlider.value < 20) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 if(FXVolumeSlider.value>=10 &&  FXVolumeSlider.value<=20)
{

  //your stuff
}
```

Comment: this has helped me however it is the same code as above but thanks anyway!